# What URL's characteristics have a real impact on the UX?

Tags: user-expectation, urls, seo, mental-models

I'm starting a blog soon so I've been thinking about what I should take into account when choosing an URL.

Some variables I've thought about: Length, meaning, suffix, memorability, SEO.
Related to these my thoughts:

- Without considering other variables: "the shorther the better". One reason is to prevent typing errors. Although **I don't think it makes a big difference unless long means really long.**
- Short URLs without meaning < longer ones with meaning. (xkcd|4| seems less memorable than codinghorror|12| or elithecomputerguy|17| )
- If **both** short and long URLs provide **the same meaning**, again: "the shorter the better".
- **.com** seems to be "the default" suffix in users' minds. **I can't find a really good reason to add .com.otherSuffix** if you have the chance to go just with the .com .
- Positive/negative implications of similar words cointained in the URL. (e.g.: go**deth**)
- A lot of **people use a search engine to get to your page** so the most searchable the better.

So, **what characteristics of the URLs affect UX and which of them are the most relevant?**

*Any **research** on the topic **would be very useful**.*

Comment: +1 I briefly looked at SIGCHI publications and couldn't find anything relevant. Definitely and interesting topic.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator

Comment: '.com seems to be "the default" suffix in users' minds' -- this is most likely not the case globally. In Germany, for example, I’d expect users to try `.de` before `.com` (many users even type *facebook.de* or *wikipedia.de*). See also: [User perception on non “.com” top level domains](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/23549/17023) and [Does a country specific top level domain (TLD) affect perception of a (non-US) community site?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/41938/17023).

Answer (score 5):

The only reference to research which I found was on the site usability.gov which did some research on optimal url names for government organization. To quote [the article](http://www.usability.gov/get-involved/blog/2007/03/creating-usable-domain-names.html)

> When the General Services Administration (GSA) changed the names of
>   the U.S. government's official Web portals from FirstGov.gov to
>   USA.gov and FirstGov en español.gov to GobiernoUSA.gov, we researched
>   domain name options and usable domain name characteristics. The
>   strategies for selecting domain names discussed in this article apply
>   to top-level domain names, not to all types of URLs.
>
> **Ten Characteristics of Usable Domain Names** Between our research and experience at GSA, we uncovered 10 characteristics of usable
>   domain names that help to increase trust. The most usable domain names
>   are:
>
> - short (12 characters or less)
> - guessable
> - easy to spell
> - easy to type
> - easy to say and pronounce memorable
> - meaningful to customers
> - meaningful to Web site partners
> - meaningful in the intended language
> - run together without punctuation, if compound words (e.g.,    GobiernoUSA.gov)

The [same article also states](http://www.usability.gov/get-involved/blog/2007/03/creating-usable-domain-names.html) the name can cause confusion about the objective of the site if not chosen carefully. To quote the same article

> FirstGov.gov had never been a popular name for the official portal of
>   the U.S. government. It was redundant and awkward to say. In fact, GSA
>   conducted several focus groups and learned that many members of the
>   public thought FirstGov.gov referred to a bank or an insurance
>   company, despite the .gov suffix. Some government agencies were
>   hesitant to provide the required link on their homepages because the
>   name didn't mean anything to their customers. In addition, Web logs
>   showed that thousands of people were already typing "USA.gov" into
>   their browsers, guessing at what the name should be.

Lastly if your planning to be in a specific language, then your blog url should be something that makes sense in that language. To quote [the same article](http://www.usability.gov/get-involved/blog/2007/03/creating-usable-domain-names.html)

> The name originally chosen for the Spanish-language site also had
>   issues; it was a hybrid-language name. "FirstGov en español" did not
>   describe the site from a Spanish-speaking point of view. "Español"
>   means "Spanish" but "FirstGov" has no meaning in the Spanish language.
>   In September 2006, GSA conducted an online survey of Spanish speakers
>   in the U.S. to test five possible names for the Spanish portal.
>   GobiernoUSA.gov was the clear favorite because "gobierno" means
>   "government" in Spanish.

Another good reference is [Neilson's article on the URL as a UI](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/url-as-ui/)

Comment: The very last paragraph in your last link seems important: "We found that searchers are particularly interested in the URL when they are assessing the credibility of a destination. If the URL looks like garbage, people are less likely to click on that search hit. On the other hand, if the URL looks like the page will address the user's question, they are more likely to click."